# Finding and Editing Multiple Regex Matches on the Same Line

Tags: ruby, regex, gollum-wiki

I want to add markdown to key phrases in a (gollum) wiki page that will link to the relevant wiki page in the form:

```
This is the key phrase.
```

Becomes

```
This is the [[key phrase|Glossary#key phrase]].
```

I have a list of key phrases such as:

```
keywords = ["golden retriever", "pomeranian", "cat"]
```

And a document:

```
Sue has 1 golden retriever. John has two cats.
Jennifer has one pomeranian. Joe has three pomeranians.
```

I want to iterate over every line and find every match (that isn't already a link) for each keyword. My current attempt looks like this:

```
File.foreach(target_file) do |line|
    glosses.each do |gloss|
        len = gloss.length
        # Create the regex. Avoid anything that starts with [
        # or (, ends with ] or ), and ignore case.
        re = /(?<![\[\(])#{gloss}(?![\]\)])/i
        # Find every instance of this gloss on this line.
        positions = line.enum_for(:scan, re).map {Regexp.last_match.begin(0) }
        positions.each do |pos|
            line.insert(pos, "[[")
            # +2 because we just inserted 2 ahead.
            line.insert(pos+len+2, "|#{page}\##{gloss}]]")
        end
    end
    puts line
end
```

However, this will run into a problem if there are two matches for the same key phrase on the same line. Because I insert things into the line, the position I found for each match isn't accurate after the first one. I know I could adjust for the size of my insertions every time but, because my insertions are a different size for each gloss, it seems like the most brute-force, hacky solution.

Is there a solution that allows me to make multiple insertions on the same line at the same time without several arbitrary adjustments each time?

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/qY5zV6/2)?

Comment: @BryceDrew Thanks for the response. That seems mostly correct, but it doesn't do any look ahead or behind assertions, which would prevent [adding the link to existing links](https://regex101.com/r/cU3qI1/3). Ideally my script would be ran on a document after it was manually updated, to add new links (without messing with existing ones).

Comment: @BryceDrew I've found my answer, largely based on your example. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at @BryceDrew's online python version, I realized ruby probably also has a way to fill in the match. I now have a much more concise and faster solution.

First, I needed to make regexes of my glosses:

```
glosses.push(/(?<![\[\(])#{gloss}(?![\]\)])/i)
```

Note: The majority of that regex is look-ahead and look-behind assertions to prevent catching a phrase that's already part of a link.

Then, I needed to make a [union](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html#method-c-union) of all of them:

```
re = Regexp.union(glosses)
```

After that, it's as simple as doing [gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) on every line, and filling in my matches:

```
File.foreach(target_file) do |line|
  line = line.gsub(re) {|match| "[[#{match}|Glossary##{match.downcase}]]"}
  puts line
end
```

Comment: You probably want to put a word boundary on either side of your regular expression to avoid catching e.g. "catapult" for "cat." Something like this: `re = /\b#{Regexp.union(glosses)}\b/`.

Comment: @Jordan I've thought about this but I do want to catch plurals and verb endings, so it's a trade between false negatives and false positives.